# Adjusting width of page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

My page is of the following structure:

```
<container>
   <header>
   <main-content>
   <footer>
</container>
```

I'm adjusting the width of the container using `javascript` by the following code:

```
function getPageSize() {
            var de = document.documentElement;
            var w = window.innerWidth || self.innerWidth || (de && de.clientWidth) || document.body.clientWidth;
            var h = window.innerHeight || self.innerHeight || (de && de.clientHeight) || document.body.clientHeight;
            arrayPageSize = [w, h];
            return arrayPageSize;
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var page = getPageSize();
            var x = page[0];
            var y = page[1];
            $("#container").css({width: (x) + 'px'});
```

**EDIT**

Now, I'm using a slider [setting a `div` to width `9999em` and inserting slider elements in it].The page opens good when the browser window is maximized.

Is there any better way of achieving this for different resolutioned-devices, so that when I press `(Ctrl)+(-)`, the page remains gets smaller revealing the other `screens`. How can I make the page remain in the middle, without revealing the other `screens`.

Here is the image:
[image]

*One thing that I experimented was*: If I set the width of the `container` element in `px`, I get the desired results. But, I can't set the width of the `container` (whose width I'm setting using (`$(window).width()`) beforehand, as it'll depend upon the different devices.

Comment: use Jquery and use `$(window).width()`

Comment: @Ankur: I even tried that. Please see my edit.

Comment: If you want to set the width of your div container equal to width of your window size then the look at answer by [Rahul garg](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14089583/662250)

Answer (score 2):

what about:

```
width: auto
```

or

```
width: 100%
```

since it is most parent container of your page...

*After **Edit** made to questions:*
To make your container always 'centered' instead of left aligned, you can use:

```
margin: auto
```

to make the `container` always in center positioned..

Comment: It didn't do any good. I'd already tried using both `margin: 0 auto` and `margin:auto`.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var pageSize= $(window).width();
   $("#container").css({width: (pageSize) + 'px'}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at some of the responsinve CSS frameworks, which solve prblems like this for various devices. One example is Bootstrap (very popular right now), but there are others.

Anyhow, the way I keep things cenetered when I want *absolute* control in Javascript/jQuery is this:

```
var desiredWith = x;
var pad = ($(window).width() - desiredWidth) / 2;
$(selector).css({position: 'absolute', left: pad, right: pad, width: auto;});
```

This doesn't always (usually?) work in some of the older browsers, but I work at a company that doesn't target them, so I can't tell you which ones break.